# Database modelling

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to model sports games in a database..

I have the following tables

```
[sport_game]
sport_game_id
sport_game_type_id
name
description

[sport_game_instance]
sport_game_instance_id
sport_game_id
start_time
end_time

[sport_game] 1 - M [sport_game_instance]

[sport_game_type]
sport_game_type_id
type  -- professional, semi-pro, college..etc

[sport_game] M - 1 [sport_game_type]

[basketball]
basketball_id
sport_game_typeid
basketball_info

[basketball] 1 - 1 [sport_game_type]    

[baseball]
baseball_id
sport_game_type_id
baseball_info

[baseball] 1 - 1 [sport_game_type]
```

I'm not 100% sure about having the type table linked to specific sports; I sometimes think it works, but am just not sure.

What I want it to be able to have a core set of classes with generic information, such as [sport_game], [sport_game_instance].

With [sport game type] which I can modify and add more sports; its the separate tables I'm not sure about. I was thinking having them separate means anything related specific to a sport I can then join on to these tables, if I need to.

What do you think?

Comment: Surely your entries in the [sport-game] table would be baseball, basketball, etc. It would help if you could give examples of the values which you would expect in the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most certainly don't want separate tables per sport. why?

1. **Your application will scale and extend very poorly.** How many sports do you know off the top of your head? And with every new addition, you'll be creating a new table? Who's going to be managing that process? I don't know the process is in your building, but my DBA will certainly not hand my application the DDL privilege to create database objects from within my application.
2. **Reporting will be a chore.** Instead of a single select statement and a where clause to filter by sport type, you're going to have to traverse `n` tables to get any information regarding `n` sports. Not good at all. You will **NEVER** be able to know how many sports_types you support, without asking someone or putting on a post-it somewhere how many sports_types tables you created.

If game-specific fields are that much of a concern, you can templatize (I hope that's a word) the game-specific data in either JSON or XML (I vote XML for it's versatility and ready DB support via `XPath`). Your template could either be

1. A template per specific sport type. So you'll have

   ```
    sport_templates(
    sport_type_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES...
    sport_template_specs VARCHAR2(300)
     )
   ```
2. A template per sport_game (a specific game of basketball, soccer, etc). So you'll have

   ```
    sport_game_instance(
    sport_game_instance_id
    sport_game_id
    sport_game_template_specs
    start_time
    end_time)
   ```
3. A combo of both where `sport_game_template` spec is an FK reference to a parent table containing a predefined template.

Alternatively, you could have some sort of EAV table that maps `sport_type_attr` to `sport_type_attr_value` as in

```
     sport_type_id   sport_type_attr           sport_type_attr_value
     1               bathroom_breaks           2
     1               cheerleaders_permitted    350
```

Obviously `sport_type_id` is an FK ref to a parent table defining `sport_type`